# Resize and crop / resize and keep proportions with GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I wanted to create a php script to resize and/or create pictures thumbnail. I searched and I found a script which I modified a little and it works perfect.

The problem is that it creates picture thumbnails resizing and cropping the picture. I want to  be able to resize a picture without cropping, only resize and keep proportions. I added a variable `$crop` and when that variable is 1 I want the picture to be resized and cropped and when it's 0 to be only resized without cropping and proportions to be the same.

**Here it's the function**

```
function resize_image($tmp_image, $type, $name, $width, $height, $crop, $upload_folder){

/* Get original image size */
list($tmp_width, $tmp_height) = getimagesize($tmp_image);


if($crop == 1)
{
/* Calculate new image size with ratio */
$ratio = max($width/$tmp_width, $height/$tmp_height);
$tmp_height = ceil($height / $ratio);
$x = ($tmp_width - $width / $ratio) / 2;
$tmp_width = ceil($width / $ratio);

/* New file name */
$path = $upload_folder.$name;

/* Read binary data from image file */
$img_string = file_get_contents($tmp_image);

/* Create image from string */
$image = imagecreatefromstring($img_string);

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

/* Keep transparency */
imagealphablending($tmp, false);
imagesavealpha($tmp, true);

imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
0, 0,
$x, 0,
$width, $height,
$tmp_width, $tmp_height);

/* Save image */
if($type == 'image/jpeg')
{
    imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
}
elseif($type == 'image/png')
{
    imagepng($tmp, $path, 9);
}
}
else
{
// no crop, resize but keep proportions
}

/* cleanup memory */
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. If the height is greater than the width, get the ratio by dividing the new height with the old one and finally multiply the width with the ratio to get the new width, if the width is greater than the height you do the opposite, like in the example code below:

That's it, it's a very simply algorithm.

```
if ($height > $width) 
{   
    $ratio = $maxheight / $height;  
    $newheight = $maxheight;
    $newwidth = $width * $ratio; 
}
else 
{
    $ratio = $maxwidth / $width;   
    $newwidth = $maxwidth;  
    $newheight = $height * $ratio;   
}
```

Comment: I tryed your code but it's not working... Maybe I did something wrong. Can you modify the code function I posted above?